# busyboy not piping file to specified folder in node js (windows)

Tags: node.js, typescript, windows

I am trying to upload mp4 files using typescript, node js and mongodb but it is not working.

I am using busboy library for the file upload

I am using postman to test my api

when I send the file I receive the file on busboy

I can display the file info like the filename

but the file does not move to the new location

video.controller.ts

```
const MIME_TYPES = ["video/mp4"];
function getPath({
  videoId,
  extension,
}: {
  videoId: Video["videoId"];
  extension: Video["extension"];
}) {
  return `${process.cwd()}/videos/${videoId}.${extension}`;
}

export async function uploadVideoHandler(req: Request, res: Response) {
  const bb = busboy({ headers: req.headers });

  const user = res.locals.user;

  const video = await createVideo({ owner: user._id });
  console.log(video);
  bb.on("file", async (_, file, info) => {
    

    const extension = info.mimeType.split("/")[1];

    const filePath = getPath({
      videoId: video.videoId,
      extension,
    });

    video.extension = extension;

    const { filename } = info;
    console.log("filename ", filename);
    await video.save();

    console.log(filePath);
    const stream = fs.createWriteStream(filePath);

    file.pipe(stream);
  });

  bb.on("close", () => {
    res.writeHead(StatusCodes.CREATED, {
      Connection: "close",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    });

    res.write(JSON.stringify(video));
    res.end();
  });

  return req.pipe(bb);
}
```

Api route

```
const router = express.Router();
router.post("/", requireUser, uploadVideoHandler);
export default router;
```